# TranslateThis Button

Tags: javascript, button, flags, translate

just now i saw "TranslateThis Button" which is the script for translate the webpage using javascript.  is there any chance to display language flags(ex: only four flags) with out dropdown? please help me.[link text](http://translateth.is/)

here is the code `

```
<!-- Begin TranslateThis Button -->

<div id="translate-this"><a href="http://translateth.is/" class="translate-this-button">Translate</a></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TranslateThis();
</script>

<!-- End TranslateThis Button -->
```

`

Comment: "It translates any page quickly using Ajax and the Google Language API" - it's not faster than google translate, it IS google translate.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want to modify the script to change how it works?

Comment: actually in that(above i sent link) site all languages are displaying in dropdown box. but i want to display without dropdown and also display only four language flags in the <div>. is there any chance to customize?

Comment: The FAQ (http://translateth.is/faq) indicates that you can change the languages that are displayed, but I don't see any way to remove the dropdown (without hacking the code).

Comment: i don't want hack that code. i am asking is there a chance to display icons without dropdown?

Comment: As @Blogbeard has said - the only way to achieve the behaviour you want would be to look at the TranslateThis code, make changes to it, and then use it (more commonly known, within programmer circles, as "hacking" - as opposed to the movie definition of that term). That is the only way it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my bad english. This question is old but You can change like this by example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://x.translateth.is/translate-this.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
TranslateThis({
undoText : 'Undo &raquo;',
panelText : 'Translate Into:',
moreText : '36 More Languages &raquo;',
busyText : 'Translating page...',
cancelText : 'cancel',
ddLangs : [
    'en',
    'de',
    'it',
    'es',
],
noBtn : false
});
```